# Certain CSS elements (a links, styling) don't open or load on hover, until I click the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I'm a rookie Front-End Dev and I have this side-project that I'm doing for a fictional hotel chain. I modified a template to contain some custom styling for some elements that I added to the template (eg. dropdown menu on nav elements) on a seperate css file. Now it behaves rather odd and I have to double click a lot of elements on the page which is annoying. Could anyone point me in the right direction to fixing it ? My javascript seems to be loading fine and the template didn't behave like this before.

Have a look for yourself -
https://capitalresorts.aerobatic.io/

Cheers

Comment: i used to have this common problem. it's your css file has a comment in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the ".dropdown-backdrop" class being fixed. Try making it relative:

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
    position: relative;
}
```

Protip: Always check your page with the developer console. (F12 or right click page and select "inspect") Saves you for alot of pain.

Comment: Thank you so much @BlitZz, I do use the developer console .. but I just had no idea where to start or why it was behaving this way. Thank you again XD

Comment: No worries man! Take care :D Remember to make the question answered so that other people don't waste their time trying to answer you ;)